Manually set display for windows in WPF, and open the windows Maximized
I am looking to programmatically set which display my windows are shown on. This below mostly works...however, it only works if I set the WindowState to Minimized. If it is set to Maximized, it still opens/shows on the main display every time. I even tried setting it to Minimized, and then switching it to Maximized after, it still goes to the main display. Windows Startup Location is set to Manual.
int screenIndexToUse = 1; System.Windows.Forms.Screen[] scr = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens;
            this.Left = scr[screenIndexToUse].Bounds.Left;
            this.Top = scr[screenIndexToUse].Bounds.Top;
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;

So to summarize, I need to manually set which display the user wants the windows to open on, and I need the window to be maximized when it opens. The above works perfectly, but only when WindowState is minimized.

This didn't directly answer the question I asked, but it led me to the answer! Thank you.

Adding the below lines to the app.manifest made it start working!
    <application>
        <!-- Windows 10 -->
        <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />
    </application>
</compatibility>

<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
        <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2, PerMonitor</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
</application>

